# How to correctly extend a defined object?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am looking to a nice blog series called relearning Backbone. I wanted to give a try to some code there to make sure I get better at it, since I am kind of new to Javascript.

The code I want to run is very simple

```
var MovieApp = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Templates: {}
};

var MovieApp.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend ({

    defaults: {
    title: 'Bag IT',
    year: 2010,
    averageRating: 4.6,
    rating: 'NR'
    },

    initialize: function() {
    console.log('Movie Model Create');
    }

});

var movie = new MovieApp.Models.Movie();
```

But when I load the page, the following error is show on the console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

and the line that is pointing is this one

```
var MovieApp.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend ({
```

I spend a couple of hours looking at it and I dont understand why. Probably I am missing something very basic, but I cant see it.

Al the necessary libraries are already loaded.

Appreciate if anyone can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MovieApp.Models.Movie` is not a variable.

`MovieApp` is a variable.

`MovieApp.Models` is a child-property.
`MovieApp.Models.Movie` is a grandchild.

Only variables use `var`, and only when they're declared.

Instead of `var`, just state that you're changing/adding the property: `x.y = z;`

Comment: Altough the other answers helped me to resolve the error, this post helped me to understand why. I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `var` in front of `var MovieApp.Models.Movie`.

Answer (score 0):

remove `var` from `var MovieApp.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend ({`